# CakePHP reverse routing not working

Tags: routes, reverse, cakephp-3.0

I've looked around and while there's a number of similar questions to this, an answer has never been given that works:

I'm using CakePhp 3.0. I am attempting to connect and link some basic page urls to the framework.

In terms of normal routing this has worked as expected. For debugging purposes I have stripped out all routes, so the following are the only active routes at the moment:

```
Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home', '_name' => 'home']);
    $routes->connect('/events', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'events', '_name' => 'events']);
    $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
});
```

If you manually go to `/` or `/events` these work as expected.

Now, if I attempt to reverse route (as is best practice), I use the following:

```
echo $this->Html->link('News', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'home', '_full' => true] );
```

.. and ..

```
echo $this->Html->link('Events', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'events', '_full' => true] );
```

These incorrectly give me `/pages/home` and `/pages/events`. In fact, `/` and `/events` are what is required.

Surely, this is one of the most simple uses of the reverse routing process.. so it must be achievable. However - the documentation isn't at all clear about this. It may be in there, but I have read it quite a few times.

Can anyone explain how to correctly do this?

Thanks

Rick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `connect()` is slightly incorrect. The `_name` parameter should be in the third argument of the function call:

```
$routes->connect('/events', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'events'], ['_name' => 'events']);
```

So you can just use the route name in your template:

```
$this->Html->link('Events', ['_name' => 'events']);
```

Comment: Many thanks. A second pair of eyes and it's obvious.